# How to store multiselected values in an single field Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony

Hi I have a Entity which have one field called "Emails": So I have implemented multiple select box to store it in db, user can assign multiple emails.As of now the options are static

[image]

So, what data type would be better to store it into a single field in mysql. So that on edit page it , also need to keep selected.

I am using symfony2 with mysql.

Please suggest

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this is a `OneToMany` doctrine relationship? I guess you need one Entity (eg. User), and another one (Email) which contains the emails. So one user can select multiple emails. See [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking, that thing.. thanks

Comment: If it's not a relation with another entity, it will be a Collection, if it's not, you can specify the field as "array" in your entity.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: **do not** store multiple values in a single field, this a recipe for disaster. Modification and searching on such fields is a nightmare. stackoverflow is full of such questions.

The right solution is to store each value in its own record in a separate table. So, your entity table will probably have an `id` field that uniquely identifies the entity. Have another table called `entity_emails_to` table with entity id and email fields. If an entity has 3 recipients, then you will have 3 records for that entity in this table.

Comment: is right. You need to implement a m:n relationship to store this properly.

Comment: made it a simple text field (instead of select) and define a new setting where you put the list of available tokens (LOCATION_OWNER, etc). Then you can do the same think you are doing now with select2 and simply join the results with “;” and save them as string. how is this solutions?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand what you are getting at.